# Hover and active property not working on table

Tags: html, css, hover, css-tables, pseudo-class

I have table in a site am working on, I have set the hover property and active background color property to be `transparent` but its till show black color on hover. I tried everything to override it, including copying of the css path. Even in firebug I can't find it.

```
.tableizer-table tr:hover, .tableizer-table td:hover, .tableizer-table th:hover,
.tableizer-table tr:active
{ background-color: transparent!important;}

.table.tableizer-table  tbody tr:hover td,
.table.tableizer-table  tbody tr:hover th {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

You can find the table here: `http://95.142.161.62/design/node/32`

Comment: On the link, I cannot see any black backgrounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case transparency is not working use instead.

```
background-color: #111;
   filter: alpha(opacity=30);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=30);
   opacity:0.3;
   -moz-opacity: 0.30; 
   zoom: 1;
```